How to review the question and improve it?
I posted a question on Stack Overflow, but it got voted down.
I can't find out why anybody votes it down, but I want to know the possible reasons, and fix the problems.
Would you vote it down?
If so, why?
Possible reasons:

The question is duplicated.
The question is unclear.
The question is off-topic.

The first is excluded.
If it is the second, then how can I improve my phrasing?
If it is the third, then where should I post the question?

The expression is impolite.

I was not questioning the ability of React developers. I was curious about how React works, instead of questioning that React won't work in certain scenarios.

You have a single downvote in 5 months, and that was was the day the post was made. Asking why people downvoted is always the same answer, and what the tool tip tells you; someone found the post lacked research effort, or they found it not useful or not helpful. Asking after a single vote is unlikely worth file as well (thpugj you may well suffer the meta effect now); if your post was getting several votes it might denote a trend, but one vote means little.

All 3 reasons you listed are reasons for closing the question rather than downvoting. Sure, people might downvote the question when they vote to close, but since there are no close votes I doubt any of these reasons apply to the linked question.

@ThomA I'm actually asking what YOU think of the question. I want to improve my question, but don't know how.

@ThomA From your answer, it seems that a question that may not help others is not welcomed on StackOverflow. Is it true?

I didn't say that at all, @OrthoPole . My main point was that "worrying" about a single downvote made on a post over the course of 5 months (almost 6) is not worth worrying about.

@ThomA Can I say, if I follow the 3 main rules listed in my question, then a small number of downvotes do not really matter? I took it serious because I'm not a native speaker and thought maybe there is something unclear. Also, during discussion, I found many people misunderstood my question.

"I want to know how React implements state hook" sounds poorly focused but I honestly feel like a good answer wouldn't be too unreasonable. Maybe I'm wrong. Either way I could see how someone may not think its a good question, but like others have commented - its not usually worth worrying about a downvote or two.

I don't understand why there is a question. You write: "In this code, if visible is true, then child component is render and text state is filled. But if visible is false, then child component is not rendered. How can React know when to skip the state not rendered?" - well, maybe it knows by checking the value of visible? If there's a reason why you think it shouldn't be able to just do that directly, then that isn't clear from how you wrote the question.

But actually, it's hard to make much sense of what you've written at all. I recommend reading Advice for non-native English speakers.

@KarlKnechtel It’s clear in the question. “But if a child component does not always appear, the order should be broken like this” React’s hook state management depends on orders of hook calls being consistent but the visibility check makes the global list of calls inconsistent, how is this not a problem? It’s a precise question with a specific answer. If folks aren’t familiar with React it might seems like a vacuous question, but then they shouldn’t be voting on it. The wording could be a bit cleaner but it’s a fine question.

@KarlKnechtel In the first paragraph, I said I think React fill in the states in the order it is called. In the code example, the number of components being rendered decreases. The key point is that, the state that is needed to fill in decreases, and how React knows exactly which state should be skipped. Do you think this expression is better and more explicit?
